# INSERT query runs slowly when there is a non-clustered column store index

Tags: sql-server, insert, sql-server-2016

I have a big test table in my local host database (16 CPU, 124 GB RAM), which has nonclustered column store index. Every day I insert 10 million rows into this table. I found that my system runs very slowly without ending.

I see 2 queries which run parallel without ending and they make system extremely slow:

Query 1:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ABC
```

Query 2:

```
ALTER NONCLUSTERED COLUMN STORED INDEX TABE ABC.
```

My questions:

1. Inserting into nonclustered column store index is very slow because it inserts new records and change the index at the same time. is that correct?
2. Do I need to disable the INDEX before INSERT and enable INDEX after INSERT to improve the performance?

i use SQL Server 2016 and this Version allows us to INSERT, UPDATE table with nonclustered column stored index.

Thank you

Comment: That `INSERT` statement isn't complete, and neither is the `ALTER` statement (which also contains syntax errors). Can you provide more complete statements please?

Comment: i can only provide test statement, the complete statement is very long. Otherwise, this is a Example which show an INSERT to  table having non clustered column stored Index

Answer (score 0):

Those can't be running *in parallel* since according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/using-nonclustered-columnstore-indexes?view=sql-server-2014):

> Once you create a nonclustered columnstore index on a table, you cannot directly modify the data in that table. A query with INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE will fail and return an error message. To add or modify the data in the table, you can do one of the following:

- Disable the columnstore index. You can then update the data in the table. If you disable the columnstore index, you can rebuild the columnstore index when you finish updating the data. For example:
- Drop the columnstore index, update the table, and then re-create the columnstore index with CREATE COLUMNSTORE INDEX. For example:

**EXAMPLE**

```
ALTER INDEX mycolumnstoreindex ON mytable DISABLE;  
-- update mytable --  
ALTER INDEX mycolumnstoreindex on mytable REBUILD  


DROP INDEX mycolumnstoreindex ON mytable  
-- update mytable --  
CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX mycolumnstoreindex ON mytable;
```

So yes, you need to either `DISABLE` before the `INSERT` and `REBUILD` after the `INSERT`, **or** `DROP` then index before the `INSERT` and `CREATE` it again after the `INSERT`. I'm guessing the *runs slow and never finishes* is a blocking issue seperate from this index.

If the question was more generic, for a regular `NONCLUSTERED INDEX`, it could be beneficial to drop and recreate the index when you are trying to insert a large number of records, like 10 million in your case, since

- indexes slow down inserts, updates and deletes (page splits, inserting / updating multiple indexes, etc)
- inserting that many records will likely cause a lot of of fragmentation

Comment: Thanks scsimon, in the sql server 2014 we can't INSERT,UPDATE table which have non clustered column stored index, but in the version sql server 2016, we can UPDATE and INSERT this Table.

Comment: @phalondon you didn’t tag 2016 so I did t assume this. The last bullets would still apply then and it would be faster to disable and rebuild.